# What's the most efficient way to multiply between pandas dataframes over multiple factors?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a Python script that will read in two pandas dataframes that share the same index ids, but different columns.

Essentially I want to make a new dataframe that contains in *each* column a melted version of the first dataframe multiplied by each column of the second dataframe. My approach seems to be working, but is extremely slow and uses a lot of memory. This problem is best shown through an example:

## Table 1 - letter abundances (letter_abun below)

group A B C ...
group1 0 1 2
group2 1 3 0
...

## Table 2 - sample abundances (sample_abun below)

group sample1 sample2 sample3...
group1 0.0 2.0 3.0
group2 9.0 0.0 0.0
...

## Desired output

letter group sample1 sample2 sample3 ...
A group1 0.0 0.0 0.0
A group2 9.0 0.0 0.0
B group1 0.0 2.0 3.0
B group2 27.0 0.0 0.0
C group1 0.0 4.0 6.0
C group2 0.0 0.0 0.0
...

For example the value 27.0 was calculated by multiplying the count of B in group2 (3) by the abundance of group2 in sample1 (9).

My current approach is to melt Table 1 so that there are 3 columns - for letter, group, and count. I next repeat the count column for the total number of samples (and remove the original column). I the multiply the 2 dataframes since the columns now match and specify that the index level to use is "group".

```
import pandas as pd

# Read in input files.
letter_abun = pd.read_table("letter_abun_input.txt", sep="\t")
sample_abun = pd.read_table("sample_abun_input.txt", sep="\t", index_col="group")

# Melt letter_abun.
output_table = pd.melt(letter_abun, id_vars=["group"], var_name="letter",
                      value_name="count")

# Set multi-level index to be letter and group columns.
output_table.set_index(["letter", "group"], inplace=True)

# Loop over all samples in sample_abun and add them into the table
# (equal to the unnormalized count for now).
for sample in sample_abun.columns:
    output_table[sample] = output_table["count"]

# Drop "count" column.
output_table.drop(["count"], axis=1, inplace=True)

output_table = output_table.multiply(sample_abun, level="group")

print(output_table)
```

This code works fine for small input files, but the CPU time and memory usage really jumps up with even moderately sized files. When tables with 4415 groups, 158 samples, and 6000 "letters" (unique strings) are input the run-time is 1.5 hours and ~70 GB of RAM is used. However, the written output table is only 3 GB, so this seems way too high to me.

Does anyone know of a more efficient way to get the desired output?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generated a mock of your dataset first with shapes (100, 200), (100,200) and later with a larger (1000, 200), (1000, 2000).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1_shape = (100, 200)
df2_shape = (100, 200)
df1_rand = np.random.randint(10, size=df1_shape)
df2_rand = np.random.randint(10, size=df2_shape)
letter_abun = pd.DataFrame(df1_rand,
                           index=['group{}'.format(i) for i in range(df1_shape[0])],
                           columns=[str(i) for i in range(df1_shape[1])])
letter_abun.index.name = 'group'
sample_abun = pd.DataFrame(df2_rand,
                           index=['group{}'.format(i) for i in range(df2_shape[0])],
                           columns=['sample{}'.format(i) for i in range(df2_shape[1])])
sample_abun.index.name = 'group'

letter_abun.reset_index(inplace=True)
sample_abun.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

### The new method uses a generator to split up computation.

```
letter_abun.set_index('group', inplace=True)
sample_abun.set_index('group', inplace=True)
g = pd.concat((sample_abun.multiply(letter_abun[i], axis=0) for i in letter_abun.columns),
              ignore_index=True,
              axis=0)
g.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((letter_abun.columns, letter_abun.index))
```

---

Then I tested three ways of doing this operation.
First on the small (100, 200), (100, 200) dataset.

### OP's method on "small" dataset

```
peak memory: 3418.81 MiB, increment: 108.84 MiB
CPU times: user 1.03 s, sys: 772 ms, total: 1.81 s
Wall time: 1.23 s
```

### old method on "small" dataset

```
peak memory: 4298.69 MiB, increment: 897.95 MiB
CPU times: user 8.17 s, sys: 1.26 s, total: 9.43 s
Wall time: 4.75 s
```

### new method on "small" dataset

```
peak memory: 3337.85 MiB, increment: -356.46 MiB
CPU times: user 251 ms, sys: 95.4 ms, total: 347 ms
Wall time: 413 ms
```

---

On the larger (1000, 200), (1000, 2000) dataset:

### OP's method on "large" dataset

```
peak memory: 18478.05 MiB, increment: 15169.41 MiB
CPU times: user 58.6 s, sys: 35.7 s, total: 1min 34s
Wall time: 1min 6s
```

### old method on "large" dataset

```
**I gave up trying after a couple of minutes and uses too much memory**
```

### new method on "large" dataset

```
peak memory: 9432.92 MiB, increment: 5931.23 MiB
CPU times: user 2.92 s, sys: 4.63 s, total: 7.55 s
Wall time: 3.91 s
```

Comment: Memory usage dropped from 70 GB to 58 GB with this approach.

Comment: From my rough benchmarks I expected a larger drop but I guess that is still a win

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping, melt both letter_abun and sample_abun then join.
Once joined, just multiply and select columns to pivot.

<s>*caveat: I don't know for certain that this is always more efficient.*</s>
**I was extremely wrong**

```
In [56]: letter_abun_melt = pd.melt(letter_abun, id_vars=["group"], var_name="letter", value_name="count")

In [57]: sample_abun_melt = pd.melt(sample_abun, id_vars=["group"], var_name="sample", value_name="count")

In [58]: merged = pd.merge(letter_abun_melt, sample_abun_melt, on='group', how='outer', suffixes=('_letter', '_sample'))

In [60]: merged['count'] = merged['count_letter'] * merged['count_sample']

In [61]: pd.pivot_table(merged[['letter', 'group', 'sample', 'count']], index=['letter', 'group'], columns='sample', values='count')
Out[61]:
sample         sample1  sample2  sample3
letter group
A      group1      0.0      0.0      0.0
       group2      9.0      0.0      0.0
B      group1      0.0      2.0      3.0
       group2     27.0      0.0      0.0
C      group1      0.0      4.0      6.0
       group2      0.0      0.0      0.0
```

You can add a `.reset_index()` if you do not like the MultiIndex-ed output.

Comment: I appreciate the response. Unfortunately this approach uses more RAM than my original approach. I had to kill the job, but it was up to ~250 GB of RAM on the files I described that took ~60 GB originally. If you have any other suggestions please let me know!

Comment: I'm going to have another go at it again because I'll be encountering this exact same problem soon. I think I have a solution. I will post it as another answer.